# How to customize new google oauth button in react?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, deprecated, react-google-login

I am using the `@react-oauth/google` package for authenticating users in my app. However, our backend is pre-built in such a way that it requires the JWT token returned in the credentials response. The `@react-oauth/google` package provides the `credentialsResponse`, but only with the `GoogleLogin` component or the `useGoogleOneTapLogin` hook in the `onSuccess` callback.

Currently, I am using the `GoogleLogin` component in the following way:

*PS: I have already setup `GoogleOAuthProvider` in App.jsx as specified in docs and its working*

```
import {
  GoogleLogin,
  useGoogleLogin,
  useGoogleOneTapLogin,
} from "@react-oauth/google";

export const GoogleLoginButton = () => {
  const onGoogleSuccess = async (tokenResponse) => {
    try {
      const userData = jwtDecode(tokenResponse?.credential);

      if (isSignup) {
        // This is later used to send the credential JWT token to the backend
        setGoogleRes({ ...userData, ...tokenResponse });
      } else {
        loginUser(userData, tokenResponse);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setOpen(true);
      setToastData(ToastConstant.SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG);
      console.log("Google fetch error", { error });
    }
  };

  const onGoogleError = (error) => {
    setGoogleRes(null);
    setOpen(true);
    setToastData(ToastConstant.SOMETHING_WENT_WRONG);
  };

  return (
    <GoogleLogin
      onSuccess={onGoogleSuccess}
      onFailure={onGoogleError}
      text="continue_with"
      theme="outline"
      width="100%"
      containerProps={{
        style: {
          width: "100% !important",
        },
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

However, I would like to have a custom button with a similar theme to my website. I want to customize the UI of the button extensively and even change the displayed text. I have searched extensively, but it seems that most of the libraries for custom Google OAuth buttons have been deprecated, and only this library seems decent enough to be used.

Can someone provide a way to create a custom Google OAuth button in React where the onSuccess callback receives the credential JWT token as well?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Update : I learned that google has disallowed editing there oauth button for this specific case I am still not sure about details but its for security purpose we can only change its color, size, etc for now.